# Assigning an alias to a table made by a join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am joining 3 tables as shown below -

```
select *
from Employee as e inner join [Grant] as g
on e.EmpID = g.EmpID -- "virtual table"  
inner join Location as l
on l.LocationID = e.LocationID
```

Code from select to GrantID seems to be a "virtual table". So, it can be joined with another table (Location) to perform a 3 table join. I want to give this virtual table an alias. Is that possible ? If yes, then how do i do it ?

**NOTE -** 
i use sql server 2008 express

Comment: Which RBDMS are you using?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - sql server 2008 express

Comment: Why do you want an alias for the join of the two tables?

Comment: to use it again and again in the code that i am currently writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
SELECT <columns>
FROM (SELECT <columns 2> FROM Employee as e INNER JOIN [Grant] as g on e.EmpID = g.EmpID) as t1
  INNER JOIN Location as l on t1.LocationID = l.LocationID
```

I don't know what columns you're trying to select, thus the placeholder.

Comment: i was hoping that there was some command like this - 
(the join code here) ALIAS EmpGrant , EmpGrant inner join Location as l.

Comment: error - The column 'EmpID' was specified multiple times for 't1'.

Comment: I think you're going to have to specify the columns in the inner query and not use a wildcard (*).

Comment: Okay I selected e.empid and e.location id to get some output. Why do i have to put some column names instead of * in the inner select ?

Comment: You're creating a temp table whose columns are based on the column names of the joined tables.  You're specifying a wildcard, so you're getting all the columns. The column names in a table have to be unique.  You're creating a conflict because you have the same column names in two tables.  So you need to tell the engine either what cols to select, or specify aliases for the cols.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

How about a CTE (Common Table Expression)? Like this:

```
WITH    my_cte
          AS ( SELECT   e.EmpID as e_EmpID, g.* -- expand column list to only include required columns
               FROM     Employee AS e
                        INNER JOIN [Grant] AS g ON e.EmpID = g.EmpID -- "virtual table"  

             )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    my_cte
            INNER JOIN Location AS l ON l.LocationID = my_cte.LocationID;
```

Just know that if you refer to a CTE multiple times in the subsequent query the entire query is re-executed. If you need to refer to the CTE multiple times consider storing the results in a temp table first, then executing your query to join against the temp table.

Comment: Don't know CTE, temp table etc. I am a beginner. Will these alter the database i am practicing on ?

Comment: No, a CTE will not alter the database, nor will a temp table. The results of a CTE will only exist while the query is executing. CTEs are also known as "inline views" for this reason, they are written into the query and they only exist during that query's execution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will do.

```
select *
from (select * from Employee as e 
inner join [Grant] as g on e.EmpID = g.EmpID) as vt
inner join Location as l on l.LocationID = vt.LocationID
```

Just make sure that column names do not repeat themselves in `Employee` and `Grant`.

Comment: i was hoping that there was some command like this - 
(the join code here) ALIAS EmpGrant , EmpGrant inner join Location as l.

Comment: Error - The column 'EmpID' was specified multiple times for 'vt'.

Comment: Since EmpID exists as a column in both Employee and Grant you must provide an alias for one of the columns as to make it unique in the column-list. SQL Server is generating a derived table (a.k.a. an "inline view" same as with a CTE) and in any table all column names must be unique.